# GWT FileUpload doesn't work on Chrome and Opera

Tags: gwt, file-upload

Hi
I have some appliacation written in GWT 2.2 (tested also on previuos versions) with file upload. Basicly there is FileUpload component with Struts servlet on server side. The problem is that it works fine on IE and FF, but does not work on Chrome and Opera.

I found some tip to use gwtupload library ( i build the simplest case ) and the problem still occurs... With gwtupload I get alert with: 
"Error, your browser has not sent any information. Please try again or try it using another browser"

Simple code for gwtupload version:

```
   defaultUploader = new SingleUploader();
        verticalPanel.add(defaultUploader);
        defaultUploader.addOnFinishUploadHandler(onFinishUploaderHandler);

    // Load the image in the document and in the case of success attach it to the viewer
private IUploader.OnFinishUploaderHandler onFinishUploaderHandler = new IUploader.OnFinishUploaderHandler() {
    public void onFinish(IUploader uploader) {
      if (uploader.getStatus() == IUploadStatus.Status.SUCCESS) {

        //new PreloadedImage(uploader.fileUrl(), showImage);

        // The server can send information to the client.
        // You can parse this information using XML or JSON libraries
        //            Document doc = XMLParser.parse(uploader.getServerResponse());
        //            String size = IUploader.Utils.getXmlNodeValue(doc, "file-1-size");
        //            String type = IUploader.Utils.getXmlNodeValue(doc, "file-1-type");
        Window.alert("Upload work");
      }
    }
};
```

Deafult servlet on the serves side.

Again, it works only on FF and IE. I hope somebody faced similar problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

It could be some nasty WebKit bug. I think to remember something about a problem uploading files with WebKit-based browsers on OS X. You may want to check the [WebKit bug database](https://bugs.webkit.org/).